# Measure time of the consumer/producer's work

Tags: java, time, concurrency

Current configuration for producers and consumers:

```
ExecutorService consumerExecutor = createExecutor(...);
ExecutorService producerExecutor = createExecutor(...);

try {
    List<Callable<Integer>> callablesForConsumer = createListOfCallablesForConsumer(...);
    List<Callable<Integer>> callablesForProducer = createListOfCallablesForProducer(...);
    ....
    ....
    // submitting tasks to executors and combine them into one list of futures
    ....
    ....
    for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
        intCount += future.get();
    }
    ....
    ....
    // some business logic
    ....
    ....
} finally {
    consumerExecutor.shutdown();
    producerExecutor.shutdown();
}
```

How to measure and log the total time which will be spent by consumer and producer **separately**?

As a result I need to get something like this: `producerTotalTime=... ms, consumerTotalTime=... ms`

Should I override some of the executor service methods for it, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Numerous profiling tools are available to help you with this.

Comment: @JoeC I want to see this info in logs, that is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override two methods of `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

`beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)` and `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)`, both take runnable, so use that runnable to count its execution time (map the runnable in eg. `ConcurrentHashMap<Runable, Long>` )

then in `beforeExecute`, put the `Runnable` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the map.

in `afterExecute`, take the `startTime` from the map by `Runnable`, and also remove this `Runnable` from the map. Then using `startTime` calculate `long taskExecutionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime`
then use `AtomicLong` to sum up all the `taskExecutionTime` from each runnable.

Using `ConcurrentHashMap` you need to add only new Runnables, as adding same Runnable two or more times will overide previous one. In case you would like to add same runnable many times use some `MultiMap` implementation (from eg. commons-collection or guava). This MultiMap needs to be Concurrent implemenation (thread safe).

Another option would be to use some ThreadLocal variable instead of ConcurrentHashMap, as each Runnable executes in own (for the moment of execution) Thread. Add the startTime to threadLocal in before execute, in afterExecute take it and calculate taskExecutionTime.

The Implementation in the second case could look like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class TimedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private ThreadLocal<Long> startTime = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private AtomicLong totalExecutionTime = new AtomicLong(0);

    public TimedExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        super.beforeExecute(t, r);
        startTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        long taskExecutionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.get();
        totalExecutionTime.addAndGet(taskExecutionTime);
    }

    public long totalExecutionTime() {
        return totalExecutionTime.get();
    }

    public static TimedExecutor newFixedThreadPool(int noOfThreads) {
        int corePoolSize = noOfThreads;
        int maximumPoolSize = noOfThreads;
        return new TimedExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }
}
```

If you would like to measure how long it takes for a particular ExecutorService to run and finish some particular set of tasks, then this could give you a hint:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MeasureExecutorTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()); // any executor - your choice
        LinkedList<Runnable> runnables = new LinkedList<>(); // place your Runnables here, to minimize influence of initialization.

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (Runnable command : runnables) {
            executorService.execute(command);
        }
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        // next line will block till all tasks finishes
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);

        long totalExecutionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thanks for the great code example! But, as I understood, your code tracks timing per thread and then summarize all gathered timings from all threads, right? But my concern is that if all threads work in parallel, then the total time of the execution will not be equal to just a sum of all thread timings? It might be less than this value... Or maybe I missed something?